# How to build Console/Cron application microservices using .net

Tags: c#, .net, microservices, console-application

We have 20+ console applications for background processing(sending emails, tagging customers based on condition etc). Currently, all are configured using a windows task scheduler and hosted on a different server. it's difficult to manage and schedule manually.

I am new to microservice architecture.
can I create and run all this jobs with MS architecture.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via programatically and configuration option. Basically save the schedule configuration and apply on application. you may have to design User interface or xml file based configuration to save the schedule details for each job. In java, Quartz framework is quite popular.   For .Net - refer     [Quartz.Net](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)    [Cron expression](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/crontriggers.html#example-cron-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

To create a background process or schedule jobs you can do it in your .Net application or via the Windows Service application.
To do it in your .Net Application you can do it with [Quartz](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) or [HangFire](https://www.hangfire.io/). Both are reliable and straightforward.

To do it in a Microservice environment you can create an independent service and add your new jobs to it.
Also, even you can listen to events inside this specific service and fire it whenever each service wants. It would be quite flexible

Another option is that you can use [Worker Services in. NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/workers) which helps you to create and run your specific instance of your application (Thanks to dotnet core).

If you ask me which one is the simple one I would ask Quartz.